# Using Find function in scala

Tags: scala

```
case class Meth(name: String, typ: Type, np : Int )
def lookupMethod(cls:String,mth:String,np:Int,list:List[MyClassType]):Option[Meth] =
{ .....
val findMeth = listMeth.find( a = > ( a.name == mth && a.np == np) )
.....
}
```

I have listMeth : List[Meth] , and I want to find the method which have the "*mth*" **name** and the "*np*" **parameters** . My above code doesnt work,so how to fix it ?

Comment: Can paste a more complete code sample? Your sample doesn't include `List[Meth]`. Also, are you trying to do reflection to find a class that contains a certain method and param or are you just trying to find an instance of a class that has properties where name = value of mth and np = value of np?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=>` is written without space:

```
 def lookupMethod(cls: String, mth: String, np: Int, list: List[MyClassType]): Option[Meth] = {
    listMeth.find(a => a.name == mth && a.np == np)
  }
```